# Load-balancing; Alternate methods of keeping track of nodes?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, ds.data-structures, tree, search-problem

Reading various articles in the literature have given me only a few decent methods of keeping track of nodes before->after load-balancing them on a very large network.

One popular method uses virtual-servers and a DHT (Distributed Hash Table)[1]

The problem with DHTs is they are very difficult to maintain, and can result in single point of failure.

Recently I've been looking at implementing a tree of [counting bloom filters](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/esa2006b.pdf) for finding nodes once their position has been moved.

**Can you recommend an alternate method of keeping track of nodes?**

[1] Frank Dabek, M. Frans Kaashoek, David Karger, Robert Morris, and Ion Stoica. Wide-area cooperative storage with CFS. SIGOPS Oper. Syst. Rev., 35(5):202215, October 2001.